# How can I retrieve the last date a product was introduced to my store inventory data?

Tags: python, sql

```
+---------+-------------+---------+
| Product |    Date     | On Hand |
+---------+-------------+---------+
| Item_1  | 11-Nov-2020 |       1 |
| Item_1  | 14-Nov-2020 |       0 |
| Item_1  | 18-Nov-2020 |       0 |
| Item_1  | 25-Nov-2020 |       1 | <--- for Item_1
| Item_1  | 28-Nov-2020 |       1 |
| item_2  | 11-Nov-2020 |       1 | <--- for Item_2
| item_2  | 14-Nov-2020 |       1 |
| item_2  | 18-Nov-2020 |       1 |
| item_2  | 25-Nov-2020 |       1 |
| item_2  | 28-Nov-2020 |       1 |
| item_3  | 11-Nov-2020 |       1 |
| item_3  | 14-Nov-2020 |       0 |
| item_3  | 18-Nov-2020 |       1 |
| item_3  | 25-Nov-2020 |       0 |
| item_3  | 28-Nov-2020 |       0 | <-- Out of stock
+---------+-------------+---------+
```

I have a data frame like the one above and I would like to get a new data frame with the last date the product was introduced to the store. Something like this:

```
+---------+--------------+
| Product |  Last Entry  |
+---------+--------------+
| Item_1  | 25-Nov-2020  |
| Item_2  | 11-Nov-2020  |
| Item_3  | Out of stock |
+---------+--------------+
```

I would like to get a solution either for Python or SQL.

Comment: Tag your SQL engine.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm . . . One method is to use do a reverse sum of the days when `onhand = 0`.  This is `0` for the last group.  Then you want the earliest date for each item:

```
select item, min(date)
from (select t.*,
             sum(1 - onhand) over (partition by product order by date desc) as grp
      from t
     ) t
where grp = 0 and onhand = 1
group by item;
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though you can do things like @gordonlinoff said or something like this

```
with helper as 
   (select t.product, max(t.date) date from test t group by t.product) 
   select 
      h.product, 
      case when t.on_hand = 0 then 'out of date' else h.date::text end 
      from helper h
      join test t using(date, product);
```

I think you should keep your table with integrity, which means that you should avoid mix text type with date type. Maybe you could do this with a small and better query, but just to show my point.

```
with helper as 
  (select t.product, max(t.date) date from test t group by t.product) 
   select 
      h.*, t.on_hand  
      from helper h
      join test t using(date, product);
```

Giving you a result like this

```
product  |    date    | on_hand 
---------+------------+---------
 item_1  | 2020-10-03 |       1
 item_2  | 2020-10-03 |       0
```

So you can work with this data in a more appropriated way.